# Kafka consumer vs Spring Kafka listener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to kafka and I am confused with kafka consumer and kafka listener. When I create new listener which listens existing topic, does it mean new consumer will be created ? What is the differences exactly between creating listener and consumer?

Comment: if you read from kafka, whatever the framework/abstraction you use, there will always be a kafka consumer behind

Answer (score 4):

In the Kafka world, there's no such  thing as a Kafka listener, there is only Kafka consumer, Kafka producer, Kafka admin client... These are part of client libraries that the Kafka project provides, available both in java and in python.

`KafkaListener` is a feature of the Spring library, which behind the scene delegates to the Kafka consumer.